# Method signature with generic map extends object

Tags: java, generics

Although this Piece of code is working, it still grinds my gears:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> entityListToIdMap(List<? extends BaseEntity<K>> list, Class<K> keyClass) {
    Map<K, V> map = new TreeMap<K, V>();
    if(list != null){
        for (BaseEntity<K> item : list) {
            map.put(item.getId(), (V) item);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

What i'm missing is, to tell the method signature, that `V` `extends` `BaseEntity<K>.` This may also lead to the unchecked warning which makes it necessary to cast the item in the value to `V`.

How can I tell `V` that it must `extend BaseEntity<K>?`

based on accepted answer from @Ori Lentz, the complete solution:

```
public static <K, V extends BaseEntity<K>> Map<K, V> entityListToIdMap(List<V> list, Class<K> keyClass) {
    Map<K, V> map = new TreeMap<K, V>();
    if (list != null) {
        for (V item : list) {
            map.put(item.getId(), item);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply define it when you define the generic type:

```
public static <K, V extends BaseEntity<K>> Map<K, V> entityListToIdMap(..) {
```

Comment: why isn´t it defined also in the Map, but only in first place?

Comment: Because the "first place" defines the generic types. `Map<K, V>` uses them, but `K` and `V` both have been defined by now and V has been defined to extend `BaseEntity<K>`. Think of it like when you define a generic class - you define the constraints in the class declaration, but once you've defined it, anywhere inside the class, the type is defined to hold these constraints.

Comment: Thanks, got it! I couldn´t find any source where this signature syntax is explained, only how it´s used. if you have one, please add it!